# Non Deterministic Turing Machine

Tags: turing-machines, automata, nondeterminism

Can anyone give an example of a NDTM for a problem (which cannot be solved with DTM) with transition function?

Comment: What do you mean "with transitional functions"?

Answer (score 3):

There is no such problem. All problems that can be solved (i.e., decided) by a non-deterministic Turing machine $T$ can also be solved by a deterministic Turing machine that simulates $T$.

Comment: Can you give an example of a NDTM?  (state, stack symbol) --> more than one transitional functions?

Comment: Just any non deterministic Turing machine? $\langle \{ q_0 \}, \{ \epsilon \}, q_0, \epsilon, \emptyset, \delta \rangle$, where $\delta=\{ (q_0, \epsilon, q_0, \epsilon, \texttt{left}), (q_0, \epsilon, q_0, \epsilon, \texttt{right}) \}$.
I'm following [this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_Turing_machine#Definition).

Comment: Which language does it accept?

Comment: The empty language. It has no accepting states.